# Premake undefined reference error on linux

Tags: c++, linux, embedded-linux, glfw, premake

Unfortunately I'm having trouble with GLFW on Ubuntu Linux, yet on Windows it works perfectly.

I'm running premak5 gmake and make(this is where I get the compiler error).

This is error i am getting:

```
Creating ../bin-int/Debug-linux-x86_64/UiApp
UiApp.cpp
Linking UiApp
    ../bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/UiEngine/libUiEngine.so: undefined reference to `_glfwPlatformLoadModule'
    ../bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/UiEngine/libUiEngine.so: undefined reference to `_glfwSelectPlatform'
    ../bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/UiEngine/libUiEngine.so: undefined reference to `_glfwPlatformFreeModule'
    ../bin/Debug-linux-x86_64/UiEngine/libUiEngine.so: undefined reference to `_glfwPlatformGetModuleSymbol'
```

I think it is related to linker error but i couldn't find any solid solution for this.
I fixed other referance errors like pthread and dl by adding them to premake file.

My file structure:

- UIEngine(SharedLib)

  - GLFW
  - ImGui
- UiApp(ConsoleApp)

Here is my premake files:

Main Premake:

```
workspace "UiModule"
    architecture "x86_64"
    startproject "UiApp"

    configurations
    {
        "Debug",
        "Release"
    }

outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"

IncludeDir = {}
IncludeDir["GLFW"] = "vendor/GLFW/include"
IncludeDir["imgui"] = "vendor/imgui"

include "UiEngine/vendor/GLFW"
include "UiEngine/vendor/imgui"

include "UiEngine"
include "UiApp"
```

UiEngine Premake:

```
project "UiEngine"
    kind "SharedLib"
    language "C++"
    cppdialect "C++17"
    staticruntime "off"

    targetdir ("%{wks.location}/bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("%{wks.location}/bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files
    {
        "src/**.h",
        "src/**.cpp",
    }

    defines
    {
        "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS",
        "GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "src",
        "%{IncludeDir.GLFW}",
        "%{IncludeDir.imgui}"
    }

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        links
        {
            "GLFW",
            "imgui",
            "opengl32.lib"
        }

        defines
        {
            "UI_PLATFORM_WINDOWS",
            "UI_BUILD_DLL"
        }

        postbuildcommands
        {
            ("{COPY} %{cfg.buildtarget.relpath} ../bin/" .. outputdir .. "/UiApp")
        }
    
        
    filter "system:linux"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        links 
        {
            "GLFW",
            "imgui",
        }

        defines 
        {
            "_X11" 
        }
    
    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "HZ_DEBUG"
        runtime "Debug"
        symbols "on"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "HZ_RELEASE"
        runtime "Release"
        optimize "on"
```

GLFW Premake:

```
project "GLFW"
kind "StaticLib"
language "C"

targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

includedirs { "include/" }

files
{
    "include/GLFW/glfw3.h",
    "include/GLFW/glfw3native.h",
    "src/internal.h",
    "src/platform.h",
    "src/mappings.h",
    "src/context.c",
    "src/init.c",
    "src/input.c",
    "src/monitor.c",
    "src/platform.c",
    "src/vulkan.c",
    "src/window.c",
    "src/egl_context.c",
    "src/osmesa_context.c",
    "src/null_platform.h",
    "src/null_joystick.h",
    "src/null_init.c",

    "src/null_monitor.c",
    "src/null_window.c",
    "src/null_joystick.c"
}
filter "system:linux"
    pic "On"

    systemversion "latest"
    staticruntime "On"

    files
    {
        "src/x11_init.c",
        "src/x11_monitor.c",
        "src/x11_window.c",
        "src/xkb_unicode.c",
        "src/posix_time.c",
        "src/posix_thread.c",
        "src/glx_context.c",
        "src/egl_context.c",
        "src/osmesa_context.c",
        "src/linux_joystick.c"
    }

    defines
    {
        "_GLFW_X11"
        
    }

filter "system:windows"
    systemversion "latest"
    staticruntime "On"
    
    -- buildoptions{
    --     "/MT"
    -- }

    files
    {
        "src/win32_init.c",
        "src/win32_module.c",
        "src/win32_joystick.c",
        "src/win32_monitor.c",
        "src/win32_time.h",
        "src/win32_time.c",
        "src/win32_thread.h",
        "src/win32_thread.c",
        "src/win32_window.c",
        "src/wgl_context.c",
        "src/egl_context.c",
        "src/osmesa_context.c"
    }

    defines 
    { 
        "_GLFW_WIN32",
        "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS"

    }

filter "configurations:Debug"
    runtime "Debug"
    symbols "On"

filter "configurations:Release"
    runtime "Release"
    optimize "On"
```

UiApp Premake:

```
project "UiApp"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"

    targetdir ("%{wks.location}/bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir ("%{wks.location}/bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files
    {
        "src/**.h",
        "src/**.cpp"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "%{wks.location}/UiEngine/src",
        "%{IncludeDir.imgui}",
        "%{wks.location}/UiEngine/vendor/GLFW/include"
    }
    
    filter "system:linux"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        links
        {
            "dl",
            "pthread",
            "GLFW",
            "imgui",
            "UiEngine"
        }
    
        defines 
        {
            "_X11" 
        }

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        defines
        {
            "UI_PLATFORM_WINDOWS"
        }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "HZ_DEBUG"
        symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "HZ_RELEASE"
        optimize "On"
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a verbose build, to see the actual commands being executed, and what arguments are passed to these commands? Do the commands (especially the linker command) look alright, and with the correct libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by missing files in the GLFW Premake.lua file. Compiler can't find modules because you did not include it.

These modules defined in glfw/src/posix_module.c

```
`_glfwPlatformLoadModule'
`_glfwPlatformGetModuleSymbol'
`_glfwPlatformFreeModule'
```

And this module is related to glfw/src/internal.h and glfw/src/platform.h files

```
`_glfwSelectPlatform'
```

After adding these files in your glfw's premake file under the linux filter, you are goot to go.

Final premake file will look like this;

```
filter "system:linux"
    pic "On"

    systemversion "latest"
    staticruntime "On"

    files
    {
        "src/x11_init.c",
        "src/x11_monitor.c",
        "src/x11_window.c",
        "src/xkb_unicode.c",
        "src/posix_time.c",
        "src/posix_module.c", // Here
        "src/posix_thread.c",
        "src/glx_context.c",
        "src/egl_context.c",
        "src/osmesa_context.c",
    }
```

Also i am leaving related question here for other people.

- [Undefined reference using GLFW static in a shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72782447/undefined-reference-using-glfw-static-in-a-shared-library)

For other missing libraries, you can check glfw github repo.

- https://github.com/glfw/glfw/tree/master/src